What is known about the (in)efficiency of true score variance estimation?
In classical test theory, an observed score $X$ is defined as
$$ X = T + E $$
where $T$ represents the individual true score and $E$ represents the individual error score. In this context $T$ may be assumed to be distributed normally with $\sim \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2_T)$, while $E$ is assumed to be distributed normally with $\sim \mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^2_E)$. Both $T$ and $E$ are assumed to be indepedent with a correlation/covariance of 0. this implies that the variance in $X$, is the sum of true and error score variance: $\sigma^2_X = \sigma^2_T + \sigma^2_E$.
Now, if I have several parallel measurements available, I can estimate score reliability $\rho_{XX'}$ (e.g. using Cronbach's Alpha). In the context of CTT, score reliability is defined as:
$$\rho_{XX'} = \frac{\sigma^2_T}{\sigma^2_X} = \frac{\sigma^2_T}{\sigma^2_T + \sigma^2_E}$$
With estimates available of both $\rho_{XX'}$ and $\sigma^2_X$ I can use this definition to estimate both true and error score variance:
$$\hat{\sigma}^2_T = \hat{\sigma}^2_X \times \hat{\rho}_{XX'}$$
and
$$ \hat{\sigma}^2_E = \hat{\sigma}^2_X \times(1 - \hat{\rho}_{XX'}) $$
However, when simulating data, I can show very easily that the estimates of error score variance $\sigma^2_E$ are subject to much less uncertainty than those estimates of true score variance $\sigma^2_T$.
I will append some R-code that demonstrates this:
j <- 10   # nr of parallel measures, e.g. 
          # items in a scale
n <- 100  # nr of respondents
k <- 1000 # nr of replications drawn from identical 
          # distributions

est_var_T <- matrix(NA, nrow = k, ncol = 1) 
 # empty matrix to store true score variance estimates
est_var_E <- matrix(NA, nrow = k, ncol = 1) 
 # empty matrix to store error score variance estimates

for(i in 1:k){ # for-loop across k replications
  TS <- rnorm(n, mean = 10, sd = sqrt(3)) 
   # true scores, normal dist w/ var = 3
  
  ES <- MASS::mvrnorm(100,    # error scores, normal 
  # dist w/ var = 3*j (averaging the scores implies a 
  # total error score variance of 3)
                      mu = rep(0, j),
                      Sigma = diag(x = 3*j, nrow = j)) 
  
  XS <- TS + ES # compute observed scores
  
  C.alpha <- (1 - sum(diag(cov(XS)))/sum(cov(XS))) * 
    (j/(j - 1)) # estimate Cronbach's Alpha
  
  est_var_T[i] <- var(rowMeans(XS)) * C.alpha      
    # estimate true score variance
  est_var_E[i] <- var(rowMeans(XS)) * (1-C.alpha)  
    # estimate error score variance
}

var(est_var_T) # estimate effiency (variance) of true 
               # score variance estimates
var(est_var_E) # estimate effiency (variance) of error 
               # score variance estimates   

I have attempted to keep the code simple, using a for-loop and estimating Cronbach's Alpha myself in a single line.
With the R-Code, in each iteration, I am sampling data with total variance $\sigma^2_X = 6$, true score variance $\sigma^2_T = 3$ and error score variance $\sigma^2_E = 3$. The score reliability is $\rho_{XX'} = .5$.
Running the code once gives me the efficiency (variance) of true score variance estimates $\operatorname {Var}[\hat{\sigma}^2_T] = .695$ and an efficiency (variance) of error score variance estimates $\operatorname {Var}[\hat{\sigma}^2_E] = .019$.
This would suggest that estimating error score variance is much more efficient than estimating true score variance. However, I have little ideas why this might be the case.
Some ideas that are floating in my head:

For each parallel measurement, the identical true score $T$ is underlying, while for each measurement a new error score $E$ is drawn. As we aggregate across items, we therefore gain precision in the estimates of error score variance. If you change the code to contain more or less items (e.g. $j = 2$), you will see that the efficiency in error score variance changes accordingly. However, the same is true for the efficiency in true score variance.
The error score variance is assumed to be completely random measurement error, meaning it has a mean value of zero. This is not the case for true score variance - we need an estimate of true score mean for a proper estimate of true score variance.
If the variance-covariance matrix of parallel measures is assessed, according to CTT, the true score variance is a component of both the off-diagonal and on-diagonal elements. The error score variance is a component only of the diagonal elements in the matrix. Contrarily, shouldn't this lead to "more information" about the true score variance?

I am grateful to any comments, hints or just pointers to relevant literature!

Not a complete answer (yet):

The error score variance is assumed to be completely random measurement error, meaning it has a mean value of zero.

Variables can be completely random while having non-zero mean.

If the variance-covariance matrix of parallel measures is assessed, according to CTT, the true score variance is a component only of the diagonal elements. The error score variance is a component of every single element in the matrix. Therefore we have more "information" to estimate the error score variance, leading to more efficiency and precision.

I believe it's the other way around: The true score variance is mostly a function of the off-diagonal elements (covariances between items), while the diagonal entries (item variances) are mostly composed of error variance.

Thanks for still looking into this!
About your first point: "Variables can be completely random while having non-zero mean.":
Totally agree - however, the random measurement error, according to CTT, is assumed to have a mean value of zero.
About your second point: Agreed, I mixed those up - will edit the text accordingly, thanks!
